# How to get a value of a drop down list in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do i get a value of a drop down list and use it in a switch statement?

```js
var x = document.myform.sel2.value;
var result;
if(document.myform.sel1[0].selected){
 switch(x){
case document.myform.sel2[1].selected :
 result =  (066 + (6.23 * weight ) + (12.7 * height) - (6.8
* age))* 1.2;
break;
case document.myform.sel2[2].selected :
 result =  (066 + (6.23 * weight ) + (12.7 * height) - (6.8
* age))* 1.375;
break;
case document.myform.sel2[3].selected :
 result =  (066 + (6.23 * weight ) + (12.7 * height) - (6.8
* age))* 1.55;
break;
case document.myform.sel2[4].selected :
 result =  (066 + (6.23 * weight ) + (12.7 * height) - (6.8
* age))* 1.725;
break;
case document.myform.sel2[5].selected :
 result = (066 + (6.23 * weight ) + (12.7 * height) - (6.8
* age))* 1.9;
break;
}
}
else if (document.myform.sel1[1].selected){
  result = (655 + (4.35 * weight) + (4.7 * height)-(4.7 * age))* 1.2;
}
alert("Your BMR is " + result);
```

```html
<select style="width:200px"  id="sel2" name="sel2" required>
<option value="" disabled selected hidden>--Select from the dropdwon--</option>
<option value="Sedantray" id="1">Sedantray</option>
<option value="Lightly active" id="2">Lightly active</option>
<option value="Moderately active" id="3">Moderately active</option>
<option value="Very active" id="4">Very active</option>
<option value="Extremly active" id="5">Extremly active</option>
</select>
```

it gives me an undefined massage so i suppose it because there is an error on getting the value of the drop down list.
i tried the getElementById method but it didn't work as well.

Comment: Try 
var x = document.getElementById("sel2").value;

Comment: The "undefined" message  which is seen when we run your demo is because your demo doesn't have a form called `myform` in it. Not sure if that's in your real code too? You didn't say exactly what error you're referring to. And your case statements make no sense - `document.myform.sel2[1].selected` will (if it worked) only ever return `true` or `false`, so comparing it to `x` (whose value would be "Sedentary", for example) will never work. Anyway there is a much nicer way to implement this - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59192399/5947043) below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample. They key is to get the HTML Element and the use the `.value` property which gives you the selected value.

```js
function changed() {
  var val = document.getElementById('sel2').value;
  console.log(val)
}
```

```html
<select style="width:200px" id="sel2" name="sel2" onChange="changed()" required>
  <option value=" " disabled selected hidden>--Select from the dropdwon--</option>
  <option value="Sedantray " id="1 ">Sedantray</option>
  <option value="Lightly active " id="2 ">Lightly active</option>
  <option value="Moderately active " id="3 ">Moderately active</option>
  <option value="Very active " id="4 ">Very active</option>
  <option value="Extremly active " id="5 ">Extremly active</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have got yourself into a bit of a muddle, and the coding style you've adopted is a bit out of date.

Also, it makes sense to wait until the user has selected something before attempting to run the calculation, so I've placed the code within a "change" event handler for the select.

First I used `document.getElementById` to get a reference to the select element. Then I used `addEventListener` to attach an event handler to it, and provided an anonymous callback function. This function will be executed whenever the user changes the selection. Within it the `this` keyword will always represent the select element, so `this.value` will get you the currently selected value at that moment.

You can then set up a data object containing each possible option, and value by which it alters the BMR formula. You can then inject that value into the formula as you execute it, by selecting the entry from the object which matches the selected value in the dropdown. You don't need a `switch` statement

P.S. I also corrected the spelling of "Sedentary".

Here's a working demo:

```js
//dummy values for demo
var height = 1;
var weight = 1;
var age = 1;

var dropdown = document.getElementById("sel2");

dropdown.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var exerciseModifiers = {
    "Sedentary": 1.2,
    "Lightly active": 1.375,
    "Moderately active": 1.55,
    "Very active": 1.725,
    "Extremely active": 1.8
  }
  var result = (066 + (6.23 * weight) + (12.7 * height) - (6.8 * age)) * exerciseModifiers[this.value];

  alert("Your BMR is " + result);
});
```

```html
<select style="width:200px" id="sel2" name="sel2" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>--Select from the dropdwon--</option>
  <option value="Sedentary" id="1">Sedentary</option>
  <option value="Lightly active" id="2">Lightly active</option>
  <option value="Moderately active" id="3">Moderately active</option>
  <option value="Very active" id="4">Very active</option>
  <option value="Extremly active" id="5">Extremly active</option>
</select>
```